# Google Analytics mobile multiple properties tracking

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have some mobile applications ("properties") in Google Analytics, my question is:

Inside Google Analytics console, on "Reporting" tab there are certain properties that I can't track together with all existing others (option "All applications" and real-time tracking for example) and can only track individually. Why?

what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance